# Does a duplicate target need an answer or not?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

If I want to flag a question as a duplicate, the text for this option tells me:

> This question has been asked before and already has an answer.

According to this, at least one answer is mandatory for a question to be a valid dupe target. Recently, I respected this and flagged a question for "in need for moderator intervention" that has been asked by a user twice in 5 minutes (without answers). My flag was declined with:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags

I can only make assumptions, but I'm quite sure I should have chosen the dupe flag. But yeah, familiarizing with the help text... does not really help in this case.

**So, does a duplicate target need an answer or not?**

If not, I propose to change the help text for a duplicate flag to:

> This question has been asked before.

Comment: You can vtc as duplicate of a question without answers if the author is the same in both questions.

Comment: Yes, that is technically possible. But what is intended? The help text says, you shouldn't flag as dupe in this case.

Comment: It's intended for when a user double posts a question. That's the only reason to dupe close a question by the same user without (necessarily) having an answer.

Comment: Your proposed change for the text doesn't work well because we don't close due to the *questions* being identical. Indeed, many times they aren't - one might ask for A, another for B, however, both might be aspects of the same solution. Were your reworded text to be added, then A and B wouldn't be considered duplicates.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure, I can learn that from this example, but nobody else. Everyone else has to make the same mistake again. That's why I'd suggest to modify the help text, that is clearly wrong.

Comment: If anything, it's *incomplete*. It's definitely not *wrong*. We close question based on the answers. Not just because the two questions are similar.

Comment: Are you sure the same text is used when the question is close as a duplicate of a question without answers? I recall there is a different text in that case, but can't find an example right now.

Comment: @Ivar The help text is already displayed before you even select a dupe target.